# How to model `( A | B | C )*` (arbitrary selection of given elements) in RELAX NG?

Tags: relaxng

Trying to write a RELAX NG schema for a "tag soup" like content model (where there may be a large set of tags), I'm stuck:

Say I have *n* tags that may appear each optionally in any order.
What I tried is this:

```relaxng
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
<!-- ... -->
  <define name="TagSoup">
    <zeroOrMore>
      <element name="A"><text /></element>
      <element name="B"><text /></element>
      <element name="C"><text /></element>
      <!-- ... -->
    </zeroOrMore>
  </define>
</grammar>
```

But when just a `B` appears, the input is not accepted.
Repeating `optional` (or `zeroOrMore`) around every `element` looks like overkill.
Also the ideal solution would not allow elements to repeat in the "tag soup".

Answer (score 2):

Make each element optional and wrap everything in `interleave`. The following pattern allows each of the `A`, `B`, and `C` elements to occur once or not at all, in any order.

```xml
<define name="TagSoup">
  <interleave>
    <optional>
      <element name="A"><text /></element>
    </optional>
    <optional>
      <element name="B"><text /></element>
    </optional>
    <optional>
      <element name="C"><text /></element>
    </optional>
  </interleave>
</define>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `<interleave><zeroOrMore><choice>`...`</choice></zeroOrMore></interleave>` also do when "..." is a list of `<element>`s? That way you would not have to repeat those `<optional>`s for every `<element>`.

Comment: `zeroOrMore` will allow elements to repeat in the "tag soup", and you said that you don't want that in the ideal solution.